# Loosen the graph layout in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

I'm drawing graphs using `ggraph` that uses layout functions from `igraph` package. However, the layouts I get are not entirely visually pleasing. In particular I have a graph with very strong connected components and some unconnected nodes. The result looks like this below:
[image: ugly graph]

So the nodes in the connected component are so close together that the edges are not even visible. Right now this used the `fr` layout, but other layouts give similar results. I seem to be unable to find a parameter that would loosen the graph up a bit that the connected component would not look like such a ball. Would be grateful for any suggestions.